# ElevatedButton does not accept restrictions of SizedBox

Tags: flutter

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appBar = AppBar();
    return Scaffold(
      body: 
      Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
              width: 800,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 50,
                child: ElevatedButton(child: Text("sdf"), onPressed: () {},),
                ) 
          ),
          Container(
             child: Text("Hello"),
          )

      ],)
      
    );
  }
```

[image]

I expected that size of button will be equal of SizedBox size

Comment: wrap the second container in an `Expanded` widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can highly recommend taking a look at this official documentation about constraints: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

In your case, you have a `Row` which practically imposes infinite width. The `Container` as a direct child of your `Row` can set it's width to whatever you want but the `Container` will still pass down infinite width (as constraints) from the parent. Therefore you need to tell Flutter at this point, that you want to avoid this implicit given constraint - one working solution would be:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: 300.0,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100.0,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('LOL'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text('WTF')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```